# How to get the direct link to a youtube video in the mp3 format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, mp3, youtube-dl

I am currently trying to find out how to get the direct link to the youtube video in mp3 format **without downloading it on a computer**, so I just need to get the link leading to the internet mp3 file. I tried to do it by the **youtube_dl** library in Python.

My code:

```python
import youtube_dl
link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fATAQtY9ag'

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio'
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(link, download=False)
    print(info['formats'][0]['url'])
```

I am getting the result:

```
[youtube] 8fATAQtY9ag: Downloading webpage

https://rr4---sn-gvnuxaxjvh-n8ves.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1667397364&ei=lCJiY6fjI7P97QSmxK_QCA&ip=95.72.245.107&id=o-AFd3ju7rPL4AbxE5TTqyDlwEVYa3O038Ljvp4iTFz594&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=6d&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gvnuxaxjvh-n8ves%2Csn-gvnuxaxjvh-n8vk&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=22&gcr=ru&initcwndbps=1213750&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=BRs0-MEqtt1vrCzmr61YjwoI&gir=yes&clen=1668462&dur=253.441&lmt=1614142570111218&mt=1667375377&fvip=8&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=1311222&n=c2zXxbznF8OLQmMbvo&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAPWkeRlVf2AmqbDFXrRJSLT0IMcLmlU4pQoMty5b7zzDAiEAw50GzyfT6NucOra_4kJ2BYfoPtWEa5lOCtQEcuF-Ekw%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgFP0t2TNC_rvUpjX3Q6DqExtm0pQ5gSlYlpq_4iCv2r8CIFwzl_uW5aQ1knRCDfoVD9eVF4By4qaCBCEsZZKyPBba
```

This long link contains an audio file with the *weba* extension, but not the mp3 one. So, may be there is a way to solve this problem using this or any other library?

Comment: You just want to download the Video in MP3 format directly? I am unable to understand your objective properly

Comment: So, there is the youtube video link, right? For example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fATAQtY9ag. The program should take in this link and then return another link, by clicking on which I would play the internet mp3 file, and this file will not be downloaded locally, therefore anyone with this link can access this server file.

Comment: You could try pytube, it might help

Comment: I dont think this is possible, such mp3 file does not exist on the internet. Someone needs to take the mp4 from youtube, convert it to mp3 and host it somewhere. Maybe you could leverage an API someone else made to do this, I did find this: https://rapidapi.com/CoolGuruji/api/youtube-to-mp3-download but have never used it.

Comment: Are you trying to stream the audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube has never had audio-only video formats with MP3 audio, and haven't had mixed (audio+video) formats with MP3 audio for years.

Your options are:

1. Not use mp3. An obvious one, but pretty much anything supports mp4a these days, and lots support opus. (If you plan to use it in a browser, here are the stats for browser support for [AAC](https://caniuse.com/aac) and [opus](https://caniuse.com/opus), and [MP3](https://caniuse.com/mp3) for comparison)
2. If you do specifically need mp3, download and convert another audio-only format (currently, the choice is between mp4a or opus). This is available in youtube-dl/yt-dlp if you have ffmpeg installed, enabled with the following options (remember to also set `format` together with them):

```py
{
    'extractaudio': True,
    'audioformat': 'mp3',
}
```

Also, I think a useful information here: YouTube puts the IP address of the video requester inside the URL video, and on some videos makes it a part of the signature that authenticates you - when that's the case, the video has to be downloaded from the same IP address.